# Spring API-gateway | Resilience4j randomly invoking fallback method even if the service is returning proper response

Tags: java, spring-security, microservices, spring-cloud, resilience4j

To provide some background, I am trying to implement below architecture.
It is from a course provided by "DailyCodeBuffer" on microservices, there are 3 services, order, product and payment. Clients can call the order service and order-service internally accesses payment and product services. Everything is registered on Eureka service registry and there is an API-Gateway via which everything should be routed.
[Architecture Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKzfH.png)

So, first I created everything without the Okta Auth implementation and things were working perfectly fine. Upon calling the order-service via the gateway, I was able to get the order details by id let's say for example.

Then I added the Okta auth and now every time I try to access an order details by id, **for first 2-3 times I always get the fallback method response from the gateway. And if I keep requesting back to back, it gives me result after 2-3 times**. If I try to hit the order-service directly without going via the gateway, things are working fine. Similarly, if I remove the circuit-breaker configuration for order-service from the Yaml given below, things are working fine again. **Kindly suggest the possible reasons and the solution/direction in which I should look.**
Please let me know if you want any other code/implementation from the repo. At this point, I honestly don’t know where to look for the issue.

Here is my API-gateway yaml:

```
server:
  port: 9090

logging:
  level:
    web: debug

spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  config:
    import: configserver:http://localhost:9296
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: ORDER-SERVICE
          uri: lb://ORDER-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/order/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: ORDER-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/orderServiceFallBack
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1
        - id: PAYMENT-SERVICE
          uri: lb://PAYMENT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/payment/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: PAYMENT-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/paymentServiceFallBack
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1
        - id: PRODUCT-SERVICE
          uri: lb://PRODUCT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/product/**
          filters:
            - name: CircuitBreaker
              args:
                name: PRODUCT-SERVICE
                fallbackuri: forward:/productServiceFallBack
            - name: RequestRateLimiter
              args:
                redis-rate-limiter.replenishRate: 1
                redis-rate-limiter.burstCapacity: 1

okta:
  oauth2:
    issuer: <<not mentioning here for security reasons>>
    audience: api://default
    client-id: <<not mentioning here for security reasons>>
    client-secret: <<not mentioning here for security reasons>>
    scopes: openid, profile, email, offline_access
```

Here is my controller layer for order-service(The SOUT is printing everything correctly every time, so I am skipping service layer code here, please ask if you still want it):

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('Admin') || hasAuthority('Customer')")
@GetMapping("/{orderId}")
public ResponseEntity<OrderResponse> getOrderDetails(@PathVariable("orderId") long orderId) {
    OrderResponse orderResponse = orderService.getOrderDetails(orderId);
    System.out.println("orderResponse = " + orderResponse);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(orderResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Here is my Cloud-Gateway application class where I have setup the circuit breaker with default configs:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CloudGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudGatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    KeyResolver userKeySolver() {
        return exchange -> Mono.just("userKey");
    }

    @Bean
    public Customizer<Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> defaultCustomizer() {
        return factory -> factory.configureDefault(
                id -> new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
                        .circuitBreakerConfig(
                                CircuitBreakerConfig.ofDefaults()
                        ).build()
        );
    }

}
```

FallBack controller in API-gateway:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class FallbackController {

    @GetMapping("/orderServiceFallBack")
    public String orderServiceFallback() {
        return "Order service is down!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/paymentServiceFallBack")
    public String paymentServiceFallback() {
        return "Payment service is down!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/productServiceFallBack")
    public String productServiceFallback() {
        return "Product service is down!";
    }
}
```

Order-service logs (Same logs every time):

```
2023-01-05 10:56:22.465 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET https://dev-89319517.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/keys
2023-01-05 10:56:22.466 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[text/plain, */*]
2023-01-05 10:56:23.799 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2023-01-05 10:56:23.799 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [java.lang.String] as "application/json"
2023-01-05 10:56:23.860 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/order/4", parameters={}
2023-01-05 10:56:23.872 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.dailycodebuffer.orderservice.controller.OrderController#getOrderDetails(long)
2023-01-05 10:56:23.915  INFO [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] c.d.o.service.OrderServiceImpl           : Get order details for order id: 4
2023-01-05 10:56:24.016  INFO [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] c.d.o.service.OrderServiceImpl           : Invoking product service to fetch the product for id: 2
2023-01-05 10:56:24.018 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET http://PRODUCT-SERVICE/product/2
2023-01-05 10:56:24.019 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2023-01-05 10:56:24.028 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,1bc48b17dcb26435] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP POST https://dev-89319517.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/token
2023-01-05 10:56:24.028 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,1bc48b17dcb26435] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2023-01-05 10:56:24.029 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,1bc48b17dcb26435] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{grant_type=[client_credentials], scope=[internal]}] as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
2023-01-05 10:56:24.672 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,1bc48b17dcb26435] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2023-01-05 10:56:24.672 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,1bc48b17dcb26435] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2AccessTokenResponse] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
2023-01-05 10:56:26.132 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2023-01-05 10:56:26.132 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [com.dailycodebuffer.orderservice.external.response.ProductResponse]
2023-01-05 10:56:26.134  INFO [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] c.d.o.service.OrderServiceImpl           : Getting payment information from payment service
2023-01-05 10:56:26.134 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET http://PAYMENT-SERVICE/payment/order/4
2023-01-05 10:56:26.134 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2023-01-05 10:56:26.134 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,,] 14072 --- [/api/v2/spans}}] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : HTTP POST http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
2023-01-05 10:56:26.134 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,,] 14072 --- [/api/v2/spans}}] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
2023-01-05 10:56:26.135 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,,] 14072 --- [/api/v2/spans}}] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : Writing [[B@397bd980] as "application/json"
2023-01-05 10:56:26.165 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,,] 14072 --- [/api/v2/spans}}] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : Response 202 ACCEPTED
2023-01-05 10:56:27.744 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
2023-01-05 10:56:27.744 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Reading to [com.dailycodebuffer.orderservice.external.response.PaymentResponse]
orderResponse = OrderResponse(orderId=4, orderDate=2023-01-02T12:21:48.312429Z, orderStatus=PLACED, amount=2000, productDetails=OrderResponse.ProductDetails(productName=MacBook, productId=2, quantity=1, price=2000), paymentDetails=OrderResponse.PaymentDetails(paymentId=1, paymentMode=CASH, paymentStatus=SUCCESS, paymentDate=2023-01-02T12:21:48.794794Z))
2023-01-05 10:56:27.760 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2023-01-05 10:56:27.763 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [OrderResponse(orderId=4, orderDate=2023-01-02T12:21:48.312429Z, orderStatus=PLACED, amount=2000, pro (truncated)...]
2023-01-05 10:56:27.773 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,03f7ef4ad8f0e497,4a4d18fceb3bada1] 14072 --- [nio-8082-exec-6] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
2023-01-05 10:56:28.168 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,,] 14072 --- [/api/v2/spans}}] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : HTTP POST http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
2023-01-05 10:56:28.169 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,,] 14072 --- [/api/v2/spans}}] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
2023-01-05 10:56:28.169 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,,] 14072 --- [/api/v2/spans}}] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : Writing [[B@3460194e] as "application/json"
2023-01-05 10:56:28.176 DEBUG [ORDER-SERVICE,,] 14072 --- [/api/v2/spans}}] org.springframework.web.HttpLogging      : Response 202 ACCEPTED
```

API-Gateway logs when it fails:

```
2023-01-05 10:58:24.485 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,,] 23068 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [f9b266b7-10] HTTP GET "/order/4"
2023-01-05 10:58:24.496 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,e7049b94195ecf37,6cf05802f3dca2dc] 23068 --- [     parallel-1] o.s.w.s.s.DefaultWebSessionManager       : Created new WebSession.
2023-01-05 10:58:25.163 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,,] 23068 --- [/api/v2/spans}}] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [34ca7d36] HTTP POST http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
2023-01-05 10:58:25.168 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,60dd40f12b9da81d,070b6d8bba49f22f] 23068 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] o.s.core.codec.ByteArrayEncoder          : [34ca7d36] Writing 439 bytes
2023-01-05 10:58:25.181 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,60dd40f12b9da81d,070b6d8bba49f22f] 23068 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [34ca7d36] [862de7b5-1, L:/127.0.0.1:59384 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:9411] Response 202 ACCEPTED
2023-01-05 10:58:25.511 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,b4f5aea2726ff3fb,08f2382b1d8686aa] 23068 --- [     parallel-2] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : [f9b266b7-10] Mapped to com.dailycodebuffer.cloudgateway.controller.FallbackController#orderServiceFallback()
2023-01-05 10:58:25.514 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,b4f5aea2726ff3fb,08f2382b1d8686aa] 23068 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.w.r.r.m.a.ResponseBodyResultHandler  : [f9b266b7-10] Using 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' given [*/*] and supported [text/plain;charset=UTF-8, text/event-stream, text/plain;charset=UTF-8, */*]
2023-01-05 10:58:25.514 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,b4f5aea2726ff3fb,08f2382b1d8686aa] 23068 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.w.r.r.m.a.ResponseBodyResultHandler  : [f9b266b7-10] 0..1 [java.lang.String]
2023-01-05 10:58:25.514 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,b4f5aea2726ff3fb,08f2382b1d8686aa] 23068 --- [     parallel-2] o.s.core.codec.CharSequenceEncoder       : [f9b266b7-10] Writing "Order service is down!"
2023-01-05 10:58:25.516 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,,] 23068 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [f9b266b7-10] Completed 200 OK
2023-01-05 10:58:26.188 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,,] 23068 --- [/api/v2/spans}}] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [1c1092e2] HTTP POST http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
2023-01-05 10:58:26.190 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,60dd40f12b9da81d,070b6d8bba49f22f] 23068 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] o.s.core.codec.ByteArrayEncoder          : [1c1092e2] Writing 1268 bytes
2023-01-05 10:58:26.198 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,60dd40f12b9da81d,070b6d8bba49f22f] 23068 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [1c1092e2] [862de7b5-2, L:/127.0.0.1:59384 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:9411] Response 202 ACCEPTED
```

API-Gateway logs when it returns proper results:

```
2023-01-05 10:59:44.857 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,b4f5aea2726ff3fb,08f2382b1d8686aa] 23068 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [f9b266b7-12] HTTP GET "/order/4"
2023-01-05 10:59:44.865 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,6e2c73066610bdd2,04c9da4375862aa5] 23068 --- [     parallel-3] o.s.w.s.s.DefaultWebSessionManager       : Created new WebSession.
2023-01-05 10:59:44.946 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,,] 23068 --- [/api/v2/spans}}] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [c2145ca] HTTP POST http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
2023-01-05 10:59:44.947 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,,] 23068 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.core.codec.ByteArrayEncoder          : [c2145ca] Writing 439 bytes
2023-01-05 10:59:44.960 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,,] 23068 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [c2145ca] [fcfb2f85-3, L:/127.0.0.1:59436 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:9411] Response 202 ACCEPTED
2023-01-05 10:59:45.484 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,,] 23068 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [f9b266b7-12] Completed 200 OK
2023-01-05 10:59:45.964 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,,] 23068 --- [/api/v2/spans}}] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [143e412e] HTTP POST http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
2023-01-05 10:59:45.965 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,,] 23068 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.core.codec.ByteArrayEncoder          : [143e412e] Writing 853 bytes
2023-01-05 10:59:45.993 DEBUG [API-GATEWAY,,] 23068 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.r.f.client.ExchangeFunctions       : [143e412e] [fcfb2f85-4, L:/127.0.0.1:59436 - R:localhost/127.0.0.1:9411] Response 202 ACCEPTED
```

**Update:** I added Exception in the fallback method argument list and below in the stacktrace:

```
@GetMapping("/orderServiceFallBack")
    public String orderServiceFallback(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("e.getMessage() = " + e.getMessage()); // This is printing null.
        System.out.println("e.getStackTrace() = " + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        return "Order service is down!";
    }
```

Below is the stacktrace printed:

```
[java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:211)
    org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.constructAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:225)
    org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:217)
    org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.prepareAttributeMono(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:177)
    org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodArgumentResolver.java:111)
    org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:119)
    org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.reactive.result.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.lambda$handle$1(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:200)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:44)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:240)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:203)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:181)
    reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:121)
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:263)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51)
    reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FluxConcatMap.java:282)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:863)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
    reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2400)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171)
    reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2196)
    reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2070)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:451)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:219)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83)
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4490)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onError(MonoPeekTerminal.java:258)
    reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
    reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:295)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.doTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:280)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutTimeoutSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:419)
    reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorReturn$ReturnSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorReturn.java:162)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.propagateDelay(MonoDelay.java:271)
    reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:286)
    reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68)
    reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)]
```

**Update2:** I enabled the circuitbreakers' status in the actuator and checked before and after hitting the API. the failedCalls numbers are going up. But why? Because in my controller, the SOUT is printing everything perfectly fine.

This is what I am getting in the /actuator/health endpoint:

```
{
"status": "UP",
"components": {
    "circuitBreakers": {
        "status": "UP",
        "details": {
            "PAYMENT-SERVICE": {
                "status": "UP",
                "details": {
                    "failureRate": "-1.0%",
                    "failureRateThreshold": "50.0%",
                    "slowCallRate": "-1.0%",
                    "slowCallRateThreshold": "100.0%",
                    "bufferedCalls": 0,
                    "slowCalls": 0,
                    "slowFailedCalls": 0,
                    "failedCalls": 0,
                    "notPermittedCalls": 0,
                    "state": "CLOSED"
                }
            },
            "ORDER-SERVICE": {
                "status": "UP",
                "details": {
                    "failureRate": "-1.0%",
                    "failureRateThreshold": "50.0%",
                    "slowCallRate": "-1.0%",
                    "slowCallRateThreshold": "100.0%",
                    "bufferedCalls": 1,
                    "slowCalls": 0,
                    "slowFailedCalls": 0,
                    "failedCalls": 1,
                    "notPermittedCalls": 0,
                    "state": "CLOSED"
                }
            },
            "PRODUCT-SERVICE": {
                "status": "UP",
                "details": {
                    "failureRate": "-1.0%",
                    "failureRateThreshold": "50.0%",
                    "slowCallRate": "-1.0%",
                    "slowCallRateThreshold": "100.0%",
                    "bufferedCalls": 0,
                    "slowCalls": 0,
                    "slowFailedCalls": 0,
                    "failedCalls": 0,
                    "notPermittedCalls": 0,
                    "state": "CLOSED"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve it in the end? We are experiencing the same problem, but only with certain calls that have bigger response body sizes.